# Unity Network Discovery broadcast very inconsistent, but works after reinstall (Android)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lan, broadcasting, unity-networking

Im making a new addition to my PC game (server) by supporting an Android app (client) that will be a (custom)controller (sort of a wifi controller). The server broadcasts it's network address to the client because the client does not know the IP address beforehand. This is a LAN connection, so the client is on the same network as the server.

I have got it to work numerous times, but it is very inconsistent. If I reinstall the APK build of the android app, it works fine, but after 2 or 3 close/open cycles (like really closing the Android app and booting it up again) it stops picking up the broadcast. I have not found a solution for it yet.

Am I not cleaning old connections or something? I would have thougth that closing the app would clear any NetworkTransport thingies. The only thing I am sure of is that the server broadcast is fine because when I open the client app on another Android device, it works fine while maintaining the same session of the server.

Also, I am a complete novice in networking so do not blame me :p
Thanks in advance! :)

**Code of the client-side NetworkDiscovery**

```
public class NetworkDiscoveryController : NetworkDiscovery {

bool hasReceivedBroadcastAtLeastOnce = true;

private void OnEnable()
{
    if(Application.isEditor){
        Debug.LogWarning("Editor mode, IP: localhost");
        hasReceivedBroadcastAtLeastOnce = false;
        OnReceivedBroadcast("", "localhost:25025");
        return;
    }

    Initialize();
    hasReceivedBroadcastAtLeastOnce = false;
    StartAsClient();
}

public override void OnReceivedBroadcast(string fromAddress, string data)
{
    try
    {
        if(hasReceivedBroadcastAtLeastOnce){
            return;
        }
        hasReceivedBroadcastAtLeastOnce = true;
        Debugger.instance.setTextConnected("Broadcast found!");

        string[] networkMessages = data.Split(':');
        int port;
        Int32.TryParse(networkMessages.Last(), out port);
        Debug.Log(networkMessages.First());
        Debug.Log(networkMessages.Last());

        AndroidInputClient.Instance.networkAddress = 
        networkMessages.First();
        AndroidInputClient.Instance.networkPort = port;
        AndroidInputClient.Instance.client = 
        AndroidInputClient.Instance.StartClient();

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError("OnReceiveBroadcast went badly wrong");
        Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    if(pauseStatus)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Client stopping");
        AndroidInputClient.Instance.StopClient();
        StopBroadcast();
        if(AndroidInputClient.Instance.connectionId != 0){
            byte error;
            NetworkTransport.Disconnect(AndroidInputClient.Instance.hostId, 
            AndroidInputClient.Instance.connectionId, out error);
            Debug.LogError("Disconnect message: " + error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OnEnable();
    }
}
```

}

**When the client has received the broadcast from the server, I connect the client to the actual server and stop the broadcast.**

```
public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection nc) {
    base.OnClientConnect(nc);

    _networkDiscoveryController.StopBroadcast();
    _networkDiscoveryController.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    connectionId = nc.connectionId;
    hostId = nc.hostId;
    Debug.Log("client! on client connect " + connectionId + " " + hostId);

    // Handler setup
    client.RegisterHandler(_stateSyncMsgType, OnServerGameState);
}

public override void OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection nc) {
    StopClient();
    _currentState = States.Launch;
    OnStateChanged(_currentState);
    _networkDiscoveryController.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    Debugger.instance.setTextConnected("Connection lost");
}
```

Comment: Do you also start the broadcast again if the client disconnects? Do you see any missbehaviour on the server (like not cleaning up correctly)? Any errors on client side?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have no errors as far as I know. I also found out that on my Samsung Galaxy S6 it works every time while on my Google Pixel 2XL it works only once or twice after reinstall. If the client disconnects I do restart the broadcast listening and the server broadcast always keeps going.